# What is Naruto's age?

Tags: naruto

I'm sort of new to Naruto. I just finished most of part one and about to start Shippuden. I was wondering how old was he at the start of Shippuden? I'd really like to know as I have researched it a bit and can't figure it out. Maybe it slipped by me.

There's been all sort of answers online, but no definitive evidence. Evidence would be nice.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

From the [wiki](http://naruto.wikia.com/wiki/Naruto_Uzumaki) under *Personal*

> **Part I**: 12 - 13
>
> **Part II** *(Shippuden)*: 15 - 16

It is also worth noting that when Minato asked him his age after stoping naruto from releasing the Kyuubi's seal, Naruto told him that he was 16.

On the wiki, it also says that he graduated from the Academy at age 12, *some time passed* and we know he spent ~2.5 years away training with Jiraiya so accounting for any time that may have passed, it eventually adds up.

Comment: Oh I missed that. I can't believe he's that young and so powerful.

Comment: When Minato asked when he was about to release the Kyuubi's seal, Naruto answered that he was 16.

Comment: I don't think I'm that far yet but I'll keep a look out for that.

Answer (score 6):

Naruto is 17 years old at the time of writing. But if you think that's young, Itachi was only 17 years old in the first part of Naruto.

> Meaning he was 20-22 when Sasuke killed him.

Not to mention he was 13-14 when he killed his entire clan... So yeah, the mangaka has a really good opinion of young people xD

Comment: Can you give a chapter or come chapters as frame of reference?